# Secure sensitive web dir folder

Tags: php, apache, code-access-security, mod-security

In a app which is using ussd to make payment and later the offline app is uploading tokens to online app for use.

I would like to be shared some ways and considerations to be taken to a folder which is keepin tokens in XML format.

Currently my security measures are as follows.

- Directory listing is disabled.
- Direct access to folder gives 404 www.example.net/XML
- No download is allowed in XML folder
- Redeemed tokens are flagged in SQL database

Note: to get a token you ll need to send get request www.example.net/get.php?token=cabdher&tel=123456789&id=2
The request will return XML data

Ofcouse I head that if you have sensitive information don't keep it online but I know we can protect the environment.

**EDIT**

actual web directory example.  www.mysubdomain.mydomain.net/bin/xml

I ll thanks you much for friendly answers and help.

Comment: Is said directory outside of your document root?

Comment: This sounds strange... if you don't want any direct access to that folder, then why do you publish it via http? Don't!

Comment: @arkascha In get.php file_get_contents() is being used if I get you better

Comment: @peeHaa did my edit ans your question cos I didn't get you fully

Comment: Sure, I understood that. But there is absolutely no reason for you to publish the folders content via http for that. Only those files/scripts should be published / available via http that are meant to be accessed that way. Everything else, so everything meant only to be accessed via some routing script, should _not_ be published directly.

Comment: For me to upload XML file to XML folder am using FTP from localhost, anyone needs the file ll pass through get.php

Comment: @FetchLazy If you want to prevent access to a resource don't make the resource public. In specific this would mean placing the data outside of your document root where it cannot be accessed.

Comment: So am I going to access folder out side doc root via FTP much am in shared host